# Iterating combinations of all possible subsets of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, subset, combinations

I am trying to iterate combinations of subsets given number of elements for each subset. I mean, for example, iterate a 4-length combination that 1 element is in the list A, 1 in the list B and 2 in the list C. How the fast way to do this?

```
A = [1, 4, 5] # 1 element from this list
B = [7, 2, 12, 16] # 1 element from this list
C = [10, 24, 26, 31, 45, 51] # 2 elements from this list
for i in get_combinations((1,A), (1, B), (2, C)):
   # i1 = (1, 7, 10, 24)
   # i2 = (1, 7, 10, 26)
   # i3 = (1, 7, 10, 31)...
```

Comment: Please, provide the expected output and what you've tried so far. It's hard to understand what you mean without a better example.

Comment: Code for *get_combinations()* please. Or are you asking us to write it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product(A, B, itertools.combinations(C, 2)):
    print(i)
```

This gives:

```
(1, 7, (10, 24))
(1, 7, (10, 26))
(1, 7, (10, 31))
...
```

This is almost correct, except the values from `C` are grouped in tuples.  To flatten the tuples, you can do:

```
for i in itertools.product(A, B, itertools.combinations(C, 2)):
    v = i[0:2] + i[2]
    print(v)
```

This gives the desired result:

```
(1, 7, 10, 24)
(1, 7, 10, 26)
(1, 7, 10, 31)
...
```